# Google map api is not working well with our application

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have tested 31.5323040,35.1004989  latitude/longitude in google map api example script (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse#all) where it is not returning the address.

Please advise

** attached the screenshot of the issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxsu8.jpg)

Comment: I presume the reverse geocoder only supports certain countries, or your location doesn't have a known address. Google Maps says "unavailable" when I attempt it directly on maps.google.com, too.

Comment: In google maps is working fine , see the link 31°31'56.3"N 35°06'01.8"E
https://goo.gl/maps/v9ivYwBH9gcw9Csh8

Comment: I did. The left sidebar just shows the coordinates. When I click on the pin, I get: https://imgur.com/a/ISYRzmG

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates 31.5323040,35.1004989 latitude/longitude are located in the West Bank area. West Bank is the disputed area and this is a known issue for Google reverse geocoder. All coordinates in disputed areas return ZERO_RESULTS.

There is a bug for this in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826813).

Please see the another [StackOverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851641/why-does-google-reverse-geocoding-return-zero-results-on-some-gps-coordinates) for the detailed answer.

Comment: This bug was fixed a year ago. "Please kindly file a new bug with example failing requests."

Comment: As mentioned in the comment #25 of [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/35826813) .   Note: Geocoding API responses for locations in disputed territories will not include results or address components representing countries or any level of administrative areas. I checked the location 31.5323040,35.1004989 latitude/longitude falls under disputed areas therefore Google Reverse Geocoding will return ZERO_RESULTS.

Comment: Now read the subsequent comments.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I understand that you need Geocoding API responses for locations in disputed territories, It is therefore requested to open a Private Issue Tracker by following the [document](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to investigate this issue .